# CSS Access top label element on an input

Tags: java, html, css

I'm currently trying to style a label to change its color when I have validation problems.

```
<label>
<input id="single-select" class="apply-form-multi-select required errorField" type="radio" name="question_3897788" style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0); color: red;">
Option 2
</label>
```

Most of this information is dynamically generated. My intention is to access the top  so I can change the color of the "Option 2" text.

I currently have the following:

```
$('input[name='+i+'].errorField.apply-form-multi-select').css("color", "red");
```

But this only gives me the input field.
Any idea on how can I access the label?

Comment: your label element contain a text and a input element do you really need that ?? if you are doing some error field validations or do u need to display some error messages in screen then you can use a common error div in the top and into that div or span you can inject your error messages.iif you want the error message just below the field lile in question then try to use append method append what ever you want in to the proper element .if you really like the way you did in question then write option two inside another label tag and give an id or name to that lable then you will get a proper co

Comment: I think .parents('label').css('color','red') will change the colour of  entire thing inside the label .example if you have a button inside the label then the above code will change the button text color also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try attaching a `.parent()` to the end which matches the tag directly above the matched tag(s).

```
$('input[name='+i+'].errorField.apply-form-multi-select').parent().css("color", "red");
```

---

Thanks to [Amit kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4873715/amit-kumar), here is a solution that makes sure the parent element is a label

If you want to make sure `.parent()` is matching a `label` element, you can give it a selector as an argument. For example, `.parent("label")`.

Comment: or $('input[name='+i+'].errorField.apply-form-multi-select').parents('label').css("color", "red");

Comment: @Amitkumar That works too! Would you like me to incorporate that into my answer or would you like to make your own?

Comment: you can incorporate :)

Comment: @Amitkumar ok, I have done so -- I used `.parent()` instead of `.parents()` as it seems more efficient (there probably won't be nested labels).

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, this takes care of my issue.